# Vue CLI 4 - PWA plugin pre-cache in manifest fails to fetch index.html and doesn't register the service worker

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli, workbox

After updating Vue CLI 3 to CLI 4 the service worker stopped being registering.

Ennvironment:

```
Firebase hosting, 

"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vuex": "^3.1.1",
"firebase": "^7.2.3",
"vuetify": "^2.1.9",
"core-js": "^3.3.6",
...
 "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.0.5",
```

[image]

[image]

I see the fail is on the generated precache-manifest file exactly on the /index.html page:

```
// precache-manifest.326028534d4ff40f4be7a15fc11e84c6.js
...
 {
    "revision": "7eeb3269c508ac628b85ccfaa20744ab",
    "url": "/index.html"
  },
...
```

I tried to disable 'skipWaiting' from the workboxOptions because I use lazy-loading routes as the documentation says, but it doesn't do anything:

```
pwa:{
  workboxOptions: {
    skipWaiting: false,
  }
}
```

The error in the network tab is:
[image]

If I comment out the lines in the compiled precache-manifest file manually then the service worker works without a problem. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was in the configuration of `firebase.json`, in the section of hosting, I hade enabled `"cleanUrls": true`. Removing it made the service worker register again.

this is how it looks now, the default settings:

```
 "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```